# Vue v-model without setter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How to use vue computed v-model without setter ??
I have three inputs `inputA`, `inputB` & `inputC`, while `inputC` is computed from other twos. Editing `inputC` should not affect `inputA` and `inputB` values, but should be synchronized with `{{ inputC }}`, and by the way, i'm using vuetify.

```
<v-text-field v-model="inputA"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field v-model="inputB"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field v-model="inputC"></v-text-field>
{{ inputA }}, {{ inputB }}, {{ inputC }}

....
data () {
  return {
    inputA: '',
    inputB: ''
  }
},
computed: {
  inputC () {
    return this.inputA + ' ' + this.inputB
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `watchers` instead of `computed`

```
watch: {
    inputA: function() {
        this.inputC = this.inputA + this.inputB
    },
    inputB: function() {
        this.inputC = this.inputA + this.inputB
    }
}
```

In this way `inputC` is changing only if `inputA` or `inputB` were edited or `inputC` were edited manually by hand

Comment: If i have more than 2 inputs, say 10, is there any shortcut way to use watchers rather than repeating same code over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use the watch option, check this example:

```js
Vue.component('v-text-field', {
 template: `<input v-model='data' type="text"
   v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.value)">`,
 model:  {
  prop: 'data',
  event: 'change'
 },
 props: {
  data: {default: ''}
 }
});

var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  inputA: 'val a',
  inputB: 'val b',
  inputC: ''
 },
 watch: {
  inputA: function(val) {
   this.inputC = val + '-' + this.inputB;
  },
  inputB: function(val) {
   this.inputC = this.inputA + '-' + val;
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
   <v-text-field v-model='inputA'></v-text-field>
   <v-text-field v-model='inputB'></v-text-field>
   <h3>{{ inputC }}</h3>
</div>
```

Good luck!